# Submission requirements for tables and figures in separate files

Tags: paper-submission, graphics, latex, tables

I am considering a submission to *The European Journal of Finance*. The manuscript is written in LaTeX and according to the Guide for Authors some changes have to be made. Yet, the instructions do not provide enough detail for what needs to be done. I am not sure what is the best way to handle the following requirements:

**(1) Tables: Each table should be uploaded as a separate file. They must be consecutively numbered and should have a brief informative title. Tables should be understandable without reference to the text. Explanatory footnotes should be brief, placed beneath the table and indicated by lower case letters.**

Currently, all tables are in the main manuscript within **\begin{table}...\end{table}** blocks.

Questions:

- How should these tables be moved to other "secondary" files, and what should be the file extensions?
- How can I keep my references (with \ref(..)) to tables in the main manuscript after moving the tables to separate files?
- Should the actual tables also appear in the final manuscript's pdf? If yes, how is this achieved.
- Should the secondary files also be able to compile on their own and produce pdfs? If yes, how is this achieved?

**(2) Figures: All graphs, charts and illustrations of any kind must be submitted one to a page. They must be consecutively numbered and should have a brief informative title. Figures should be understandable without reference to the text.**

Questions:

- If external files are provided as .eps, do they also need to appear in the main manuscript (and where)?
- Do I need to embed the figures in separate tex files?

Comment: I think you should contact the journal for clarification.  My best guess at the tables is that you would move their source to a separate .tex file which you then `\input{}`. In that case references don't have to change, and the separate files would not be individually compilable.  But it is not really clear from their instructions; they may be thinking of tables generated with other software and included as eps/pdf like graphics.

Comment: Often journals are not so strict about format details for the initial submission, provided that you upload something that their software can successfully compile into output that the referees can read. The details become more important after the paper is accepted, when you need to provide files that the production staff can use to typeset the actual journal pages.

Comment: So if it's too much trouble to clarify the exact details for now, you could just try and fudge it. Worst case is that they bounce it back and ask you to fix it before they will review it.  They wouldn't reject your paper solely for not being in the correct source format.  And if their requirements are this complicated, it's a fair bet that a lot of other authors get it wrong too.

Comment: Not my field, but often the requirement to have tables in separate files does not apply to LaTeX submissions. And reading under "Files" in the instructions [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?show=instructions&journalCode=rejf20#about) it seems likely it is the case for this journal as well: "1) Editable Files. Submitted files must be editable; that is they should be WORD or LaTeX files and not PDF files. 2) Figures and Tables. Figures and tables should not be embedded in Word documents." Note how the last sentence only mentions Word.

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely between you and the journal. **If the submission requirements are not spelled out sufficiently clearly you must contact the journal before submitting.**

When you contact them I'd suggest to ask whether it's okay to just upload the compiled pdf for the review purpose. Any typesetting issues can in principle be settled at a later stage later. Some journals are moving explicitly in that direction to make the submission and reviewing process less onerous for authors. It's worth asking! Although the reality is that many journals only care about their workflow and discount additional work for the authors entirely.